# How to stop Visual Studio changing the runtime version of a DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am having the following problem, I am adding a reference for a DLL, System.Data.SQLite to be specific to a C# program, that when added is correctly added as version 4.0.30319, and my program runs perfectly.

However when I save my work and close visual studio, the next time I open the project visual studio now identifies the version as v2.0.50727, even though the DLL has not changed in any way, and as such my program will not run until I remove the references and re-add them.

I dont know why visual studio (2010) is doing this but does anyone know how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have "Use specific version" property set to "true" in referenced assembly properties.

Probably VS is picking SQLite version from GAC when it is restarted.

Comment: Thanks, once I changed that property to true the problem stopped happening.